# Adding 2 videos in 2 different scenes doesn't work??? (error #1009)

Tags: flash

I've been pulling my hair trying to figure this one out.

I thought I am doing something very simple, but it fails miserably.

All I am doing is this: I open a new document, import 1 video, then add another scene and import another video into the 2nd scene. I make sure the videos are named instances.

Now, I press "Test movie" (Ctrl + Enter), but I only get a 2nd movie playing with the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at fl.video::UIManager/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::hookUpCustomComponents()
    at fl.video::FLVPlayback/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::handleVideoEvent()....
```

WHYYYYY??????

I've tried everything I could think of, but why something seemingly so simple doesnt work???

Comment: Did you try just adding one FLV PLayback component and controlling it by code to load a different video file (instead of importing that one)? See this for **[a tutorial handling of multiple video files](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xmlvideoplayer/)**. I suggest you learn how to use NetStream API to make your own video player that follows your rules (cos generic tools can be limited too)..

Comment: Thank you for the resource, it really seems that I need to get down deep and dirty into Flash. Just thought I could do something simple like playing 2 movies without learning half of action script...

Comment: That's not half of actionscript, more like 1 out of a thousanth options... Anyway this is how most advanced programming works and video is advanced topic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some tests and I got the same behavior as you've mentioned in your question.

These are my remarks about the problem :

- I think that's a bug in the `FLVPlayback` component.
- The problem is fired when you have (at least) two scenes and when the `FLVPlayback` component(s) inserted in the first scene(s) has no skin (e.g. as your example, you have two scenes, and the `FLVPlayback` component inserted in the 1st one has no skin). The problem can also be fired when you have many `FLVPlayback` components inserted in different frames even on the same scene ...
- To avoid the problem, you can add a `stop()` in the first scene (or each scene), which I think is a normal thing otherwise the animation playhead will continuously play all scenes.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the whole point of adding 2 scenes was to easily make one video play after another and stop at the end of the 2nd scene. So adding 'stop()' in 1st scene kind of defeats the purpose...

Comment: @Tanuki You can go to the next scene after the first video has finished ( using the [complete event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#event:complete) for example ... Here of course you should know that I tried just to answer your question, but there are many ways to play two videos ...

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. Just as I am new to Flash I was really puzzled why something so intuitive didnt work. But I guess if that is a Flash problem, not just me doing something wrong then I will have to look into alternative implementation such as the one you provided.