# AS3 TypeError: Error #1009 when trying to play FLVPlayback

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My flash animation is pretty much finshed, I just wanted to add my intro. I made a new scene, imported my .mp4 video (as FLVPlayback) and dragged it into the stage. Now I simply wanted to check if it even plays... but I get this:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
        at fl.video::UIManager/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::hookUpCustomComponents()
        at fl.video::FLVPlayback/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::handleVideoEvent()
        at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
        at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
        at fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::setState()
        at fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::finishAutoResize()
        at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
        at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

I haven't even added any code yet (all I need is that my animation starts with this scene, plays the video and goes to my main scene afterwards). What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34008414/2256820) of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34003944/2256820), I think that can help ...